Using =INDEX but need the whole row to move when new lines added
Ive set up this sheet (call this sheet 1) to populate column A using =INDEX which reads from a different sheet (call this sheet 2). Sheet 2 is alphabetical and if i add a new PIP code/product in to sheet 2 which for example starts with an A and goes in A8 position alphabetically, it inserts it to sheet 1 A8 and shifts the rest of A column down a row but the rest of the row on sheet 1 doesnt move down with it.
So say i have a PIP code/product on sheet 1 in A8/B8 with prices for each customer in columns E8,F8,G8 etc, if i add the new PIP and product to sheet 2, it moves the original PIP code/product on sheet 1 from A8/B8 to A9/B9 but its not shifting the prices that were in E8,F8,G8 down to E9,F9,G9.
(the prices in E8,F8,G8 etc are manually inputted and dont come from another sheet like the information in column A and B)
This is what i have written for column A
Columns B and C move as they relate to column A using this formula but i cant do this for the E,F,G etc columns as this sheet is were that information is been added in manually to then feed another sheet
Ive got $ in the formulas, have i missed something?
Sorry if this is a simple solution or been asked numerous times, Im not very excel savvy and I dont understand a lot of the jargin used
